# Android tabs menu example

Tags: android, android-tabhost

How I can delete upper grey line ?

[image]

https://gist.github.com/germanboy/9618172 --->> codes

Comment: Would be useful if you showed us some code.

Comment: paste some code man!!

Comment: added codes from github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the main.xml file , You should change the framelayout property,
for example background

Comment: @c.mert is it useful for you?

Comment: can you post code? because on github there is not full content

Comment: I couldnt added here. Site doesnt accept my codes :/ Only i can show on github.

https://gist.github.com/germanboy/9618172

Comment: mert arkadaşım gri çizgi çıkmaması gerekiyor gözüken , istersen bir tam projeyi yada ilgili kısmı kod a ekle yada mail de atabilirsin

Comment: Projeyi mail atabilirim. Mail adresini verebilir misin ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sbicon2"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- When not selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sbicon" />
</selector>

Comment: mert, göndermedin daha projeyi sanırım

Comment: mail adresini bulamadım.

Comment: gördün mü bir önceki yorumu

Comment: Tamamdır gönderdim şimdi.

Comment: main.xml in içerisinde framelayout tan dolayı o çizgi çıkıyor. framelayout un background unu #fffff yaparsan beyaz olur benim kanımca framelayout un boyutuyla veya yeri ile oynayabilirsin

Comment: Malesef :/ işe yaramadı

Comment: ben yaptım oldu yani framelayout a background a beyaz dersen beyazolur , nedir sorun olan?

Comment: O gri çizgi hala var.

FrameLayout frm = (FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.tabcontent);
  frm.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

bu şekilde yaptım mainactivity içinde.

Comment: bir de bunu denermisin **frm.setBackgroundColor(olor.TRANSPARENT)**

Comment: Denedim sonuç aynı. Acaba border ile alakalı olabilir mi ?

Comment: aslında o tamamen framelayout tan geliyor. Ben kendi ortamımda denedğimde sonuç değşiyor. birazdan gönderirim